# Day Trip From Paris & Rome

Tags: france, italy, paris, itineraries, rome

My husband and I are taking our first trip outside the US to Paris and Rome in January (Cold I know) and we are SO excited!   We have 5 full days in each city which I know isn't even enough time to truly appreciate them, but I want to take one day trip from each place anyway!  The problem is that I can't decide which to take!  From Paris I am interested in Provins, Strasbourg, Mont-Saint-Michel & Etrat.  From Rome I am interested in Florence, Venice, The Amalfi Coast, Naples, Capri, and many more.  I know these are all of varying themes and distances, but I don't care...we love history, scenery, food, everything and we are fine with spending a long day on buses and trains if the destination is really worth it.  I would just love to hear some opinions on which of these places you would choose if you could only choose one or if you have an alternative suggestion I'm open to anything!  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Sounds like a great trip you are planning. Unfortunately, choosing which destinations to see is beyond the scope of what we can help you with here, because the factors basically come down to personal preference. Having said that, for example, a "day trip" from Rome to Venice and back would leave you maybe enough time to have a late lunch and head back. Choose something realistic otherwise you will be exhausted (which isn't fun if you're jetlagged too).

Comment: Thanks for the response Greg, but I really don't understand why my question can't be answered.  I can't really have a personal preference about places I have never been which is why I'm asking for the experiences of people who have been there.  I am interested in literally everything Italy and France have to offer, so all I am asking for is advice that may give me the nudge I need to make a decision.

Comment: @jessica Stackexchange is intended for questions with objectively correct answers. It's not a forum for discussion. There's no objectively correct answer to your question, so it doesn't fit well on this site. FWIW, most of the places you mention are too far from their respective cities to be achievable in a day. Both Paris and Rome are so chock full of interesting places you won't have time to leave the city. One suggestion, though. Go to the Palace of Versailles, just outside Paris.

Comment: You might not have a preference about the place, but you might have preferences for history/architecture/... and even for specific periods in history/styles in architecture/... and that all affects what is a good choice.

Comment: @Jessica Bonds All of the places you mention are worthy of several days’ visit in their own right. If you intend to return to Europe in the future, I’d focus on day trips around your two current destinations (Versailles from Paris is a must, for example; you could also consider other chateaux such as Vaux le Vicomte). If you don’t think you’ll go back and really don’t mind spending long hours travelling, there’s a high-speed train connection from Rome to Venice that I believe takes 3.5hrs; Venice is so incredible I’d consider booking a night there out of your Rome stay.

Comment: I suppose you mean Etretat (and its cliffs) rather that Etrat. Also, do you really mean Provins, rather than “la Province” (which is everything outside of the Paris region) or “Provence”? Not that many of those will be a challenge to do in a day. Would you be willing to rent a car and drive?

Comment: @JessicaBonds Your trip is in January, so you should consider the possibility that bad weather could affect travel. For that reason, I’d rule out Naples/Capri as an option - the days are shorter, the hydrofoils run less frequently and on Capri itself a number of shops & restaurants may be closed.

Comment: hi new user @JessicaBonds !   I would urge you to JUST stay in Paris and then Rome.   REALLY ENJOY those places, you'll end up feeling really local and special.   Running around to see a lot of different places is not good!  Stay put and enjoy!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

With 5 days for each city you will not be able to see all the places you listed. Especially if you don't have your own car.

For example in Italy, you listed some places which are on opposite sides of the country, in some cases it will take half a day just to reach your destination.. 
Same applies for France. From Paris to the Mont Saint Michel it's a very long way with public transports. You should take a train to Rennes, then from Rennes a bus to the Mont. The visit itself could take more than half a day.

So, in summary: with such a short stay I would concentrate on things to visit in Rome and Paris, and leave the rest of the country for a future travel. Otherwise you will not enjoy your stay, you will just run around and don't even see what the 2 cities have to offer.